# PlayServices out-of-date notification needs Notifcation Channel for Android Oreo (API 26)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-8.0-oreo

There's this notification from PlayServices themselves when the PlayServices are out of date on the device. This worked until Android Oreo (API 26) needs **Notification Channels**.

I'm using Firebase and therefor PlayServices in Version **11.2.0** (newest for today).

When opening the App, PlayServices (not my app!) will trigger the notification - or tries to, when compiled against API 26.

---

Is there a new version to be used with API26? Is there something I'm missing? I'm not even sure what triggers this message because my app isn't explicitly using PlayServices. My guess is that Firebase (Anylytics, FCM, RemoteConfig etc.) is checking for the PlayServices-version.

Answer (score 0):

This information might help.

[Some Updates to Apps Using Google Play services](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html)

**2. Starting with Play services dependencies version 11.2.0, your app's compileSdkVersion must be at least 26**

> When you upgrade your app's Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or
>   later, your app's build.gradle must also be updated to specify a
>   compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O). This will not change the
>   way your app runs. You will not be required to update
>   targetSdkVersion. If you do update compileSdkVersion to 26, you may
>   receive an error in your build with the following message referring to
>   the Android support library:
>
> This support library should should not use a different version (25)
>   than the compileSdkVersion (26).
>
> This error can be resolved by upgrading your support library
>   dependencies to at least version 26.0.0. Generally speaking, the
>   compileSdkVersion of your app should always match the major version
>   number of your Android support library dependencies. In this case,
>   you'll need to make them both 26.

Comment: I'm already using `compileSdkVersion 26` (which works fine) but as soon as I upgrade to `targetSdkVersion 26` the notification cannot be shown. I'm pretty sure that the PlayServices-lib needs to use notification channels itself.